# Eclipse IDE Git client pushing code to github and getting "deletion of the current branch prohibited"

Tags: git, eclipse

I tried to push my code to github (by the Eclipse), and I encountered a problem.

I did the following steps:

1. On my project (in Eclipse) : right click > team > share project > click on "git" > next.
2. In configure git repository dialog:

   - Check: use or create repository in parent folder of project
   - Click on the line inside the table, this will enable Create Repository button.
   - Click Create Repository button.
   - Click finish
3. Connect project to remote repository previously created on Github:

   - Copy remote repository URL from github.
   - Go to Git perspective in Eclipse:
   - On Git Repositories view:
   - Go to Remotes section, right click it and choose Create Remote…
   - On New Remote dialog ­ click OK
4. On Configure Push dialog:

   - Push URIs section ­ click add
   - On Destination Git Repository ­ paste the URL copied from github
     into URI text field.
   - Press Finish.
5. Ref mappings section ­ click add.
6. On Create or Edit Refspec, Remote branch text field: type
   “refs/heads/master”.

   - Check "force update".
   - press OK.

In order to push your code to github:

- in Eclipse ­ right click on project name
- choose: Team | Push to upstream

**After all that, I got this error:**

```
deletion of the current branch prohibited
error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
```

[image: error]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but your question is formated very bad which makes it hard to read.

I'd do the following:

- clone the project from github (using git console, tortoise git or SourceTree)
- Import the project in eclipse (import existing project into workspace)
- The eGit plugin will detect that this is a git project and automatically share it during the import
- You can now use the eGit plugin to pull/comit/push etc..